# HTACCESS Rewrite Rule for Query String in PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have my URL https://example.com/?hfgshdsds.

I need to rewrite a rule to makes that even If I removed the question mark , the link will works as same as before, so my url need to be https://example.com/hfgshdsds.

For the moment on my .htaccess file I have only the rule that open the php without extension .php .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
##keep redirection Rules first then keep rest of rules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php/?$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

##Adding new rule here for non-existing pages here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank very much, it works for me, and I think it will be a great solution for everyone that need this kind of Rules.